# Current Model in Proposal Provider

Tags: xtext

I try to check the spelling and make dynamic proposals based on previous inputs.

For checking the spelling I use the Validator and code like this.

```
@Check
def checkUniqueDeclarations(Model model) {
    for (decl : model.declarations) {
        if (decl instanceof Device) {
           for(input : decl.input)
         ...
```

In this code I have a Model which does exactly what I want.
But for making dynamic proposal I need to use the proposal provider in the ui project.
Can someone explain me how to get the same Model in the proposal provider as in the Validator? So I can use a similar code there.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model can be obtained from the given `ContentAssistContext`. You may need to navigate to the `eContainer` of the correct type. Please try to use `EcoreUtil2.getContainerOfType` for that purpose.